# Can I call ejb from javascript?

Tags: javascript, ejb

I have a session ejb deployed and the jndi is: ejb/HelloEJB
can I call the ejb from a web browser using JavaScript? and can I call it remotely?
thanks a lot!

Comment: "From JavaScript" in *what environment*? A web browser? A Java application using Rhino or Nashorn? A NodeJS app or server? On a machine you control, or on a client machine out in the wild?

Comment: @Crowder It is in a web browser. I want to test when js and ejb are both on the same server or different server.

Comment: @ Jacky: *"It is in a web browser. I want to test when js and ejb are both on the same server..."* If you mean JavaScript in a web browser, then the JavaScript isn't on a server *at all*, unless you're logged into the server as a user and running the browser there, which seems unlikely. I think you might want to review what's running where, and what the lines of communication are between the points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a communication protocol to call an enterprise bean. JavaScript libraries are not available to do that. And there are variations between application servers in interacting with enterprise beans at this protocol level. That's why we always depend on some Java libraries provided by the application server when calling remote enterprise beans.

So, calling enterprise beans directly with JavaScript is not possible and impractical.

If you are not in a browser environment, there are JavaScript execution environments where your code can make JavaScript calls but environment translates them to Java calls (where you still need to provide Java libs to the execution environment and may add configurations to the execution environment about JavaScript to Java call translation).

If you have a need to call remote methods from pure JavaScript, look at alternative remoting technologies (RESTFull web services exposed via JSON, XML and so on).

Comment: I saw a sample written by dwr: <create creator="sessionBean" javascript="ReviewService">
      <param name="class" value="examples.ejb.ejb30.service.ReviewService"/>
      <param name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/ejb/ReviewManager"/>
    </create> It seams dwr can do it or dwr just translate the call into java call as you said.

Comment: [Overview of DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/index.html) says that DWR interacts with the browser via AJAX and the server side component of DWR available as a servlet translate the AJAX calls to Java calls. So it's not JavaScript calling the enterprise bean. JavaScript makes HTTP/AJAX calls and the server component makes Java calls.

Answer (score 2):

You've said you're talking about JavaScript in a web browser, looking up something via JNDI on a server.

No, you can't do that. You can use JavaScript to call something on the server (e.g., via an HTTP request to a servlet or JSP or similar) and then have that something *on the server* look something up in JNDI, but you can't do a JNDI lookup *directly* from browser-based JavaScript.